# eax doesn't take parameter after mov

Tags: assembly, gdb

Looking at some disassembly and the first insruction `mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]` which is `0xf7fda858`.

I take a step but eax doesn't change. Am I reading the stack wrong? I'm new to gdb so it's certainly possible.

```
9: x/16xw $esp
0xffffd350: 0xf7fbdff4  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffd368
0xffffd360: 0x0804870a  0xf7fbdff4  0x00000000  0xf7e324d3
0xffffd370: 0x00000001  0xffffd404  0xffffd40c  0xf7fda858
0xffffd380: 0x00000000  0xffffd41c  0xffffd40c  0x00000000
8: /x $ebp = 0xffffd368
7: /x $esi = 0x0
6: /x $edi = 0x0
5: /x $edx = 0xffffd394
4: /x $ecx = 0xffffd404
3: /x $ebx = 0xf7fbdff4
2: /x $eax = 0x1
1: x/10i $eip
=> 0x80489b7 <main+7>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x80489ba <main+10>: mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x80489bd <main+13>: cmp    eax,0x1
```

After stepping:

```
9: x/16xw $esp
0xffffd350: 0xf7fbdff4  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffd368
0xffffd360: 0x0804870a  0xf7fbdff4  0x00000000  0xf7e324d3
0xffffd370: 0x00000001  0xffffd404  0xffffd40c  0xf7fda858
0xffffd380: 0x00000000  0xffffd41c  0xffffd40c  0x00000000
8: /x $ebp = 0xffffd368
7: /x $esi = 0x0
6: /x $edi = 0x0
5: /x $edx = 0xffffd394
4: /x $ecx = 0xffffd404
3: /x $ebx = 0xf7fbdff4
2: /x $eax = 0x1
1: x/10i $eip
=> 0x80489ba <main+10>: mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x80489bd <main+13>: cmp    eax,0x1
   0x80489c0 <main+16>: jne    0x80489d0 <main+32>
```

Now that I look more I get the feeling I don't understand how the stack is meant to be read. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

EDIT: clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ebp points to 0xffffd368. The instruction is

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
```

which means that the address `0xffffd370` will be read. Looking at the stack dump, indeed, at `0xffffd370`, there is the value `0x00000001`, which is equal to `eax`s initial value.